# mvn jetty plugin not working in offline (non internet) mode , however compiles successfully

Tags: java, maven, jetty

mvn jetty:run is not working in offline mode showing exception, If connected to internet runs successfully

Comment: Unable to load configuration and java.net.ConnectException

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at your pom.xml and see if there are any dependencies downloaded from mvn repository.
If you have local JAR files, you won't need to download them using mvn build. 
For example:

```
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${project.basedir}/src/main/java/com/api/core/jars/gson-2.2.2.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
```

Above dependency looks for a local JAR and therefore not online.
But:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
      <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
```

Downloads the commons-lang jar from mvn repository.

Therefore internet connection is required when you run this.

Therefore. 1st make sure you have no dependencies that require downloading.
Then, use:

```
mvn jetty:run -o
```

To run in offline mode.